# Change DataGrid cell color

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I need to color a specific cell on my DataGrid via Visual Basic (not XAML).
Specifically, I need to loop through all cells and color them.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! FYI, you'll get a better response here if you can show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you really need to loop through all cells and set the `Background` or is the color determined by the data that is in the cell?

Comment: i'd like to loop through all cells. Is it possible?
I need to color in red all the cells have "error" value but my datagrid have dynamic column and via xaml i got an error with ItemSource